# Why does my NN not classify these tic tac toe pattern correctly?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, classification, keras

I'm trying to teach an AI to recognize patterns of tic-tac-toe with a winning line.

Unfortunately, it's not learning to recognize them correctly.  I think my way of representing/encoding the game into vectors is wrong.

I choose a way that is easy for an human (me, in particular!) to understand:

```
training_data = np.array([[0,0,0,
                           0,0,0,
                           0,0,0],
                          [0,0,1,
                           0,1,0,
                           0,0,1],
                          [0,0,1,
                           0,1,0,
                           1,0,0],
                          [0,1,0,
                           0,1,0,
                           0,1,0]], "float32")
target_data = np.array([[0],[0],[1],[1]], "float32")
```

This uses an array of length 9 to represent a 3 x 3 board. The first three items represent the first row, the next three the second row, and so on. The line breaks should make it obvious.  The target data then maps the first two game states to "no wins" and the last two game states to "wins".

Then I wanted to create some validation data that is slightly different to see if it generalizes.

```
validation_data = np.array([[0,0,0,
                             0,0,0,
                             0,0,0],
                            [1,0,0,
                             0,1,0,
                             1,0,0],
                            [1,0,0,
                             0,1,0,
                             0,0,1],
                            [0,0,1,
                             0,0,1,
                             0,0,1]], "float32")
```

Obviously, again the last two game states should be "wins" whereas the first two should not.

I tried to play with the number of neurons and learning rate, but no matter what I try, my output looks pretty off, e.g.

```
[[ 0.01207292]
 [ 0.98913926]
 [ 0.00925775]
 [ 0.00577191]]
```

I tend to think it's the way how I represent the game state that may be wrong but actually I have no idea :D

Can anyone help me out here?

This is the entire code that I use

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Activation, Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD

training_data = np.array([[0,0,0,
                           0,0,0,
                           0,0,0],
                          [0,0,1,
                           0,1,0,
                           0,0,1],
                          [0,0,1,
                           0,1,0,
                           1,0,0],
                          [0,1,0,
                           0,1,0,
                           0,1,0]], "float32")

target_data = np.array([[0],[0],[1],[1]], "float32")

validation_data = np.array([[0,0,0,
                             0,0,0,
                             0,0,0],
                            [1,0,0,
                             0,1,0,
                             1,0,0],
                            [1,0,0,
                             0,1,0,
                             0,0,1],
                            [0,0,1,
                             0,0,1,
                             0,0,1]], "float32")

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(2, input_dim=9, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=sgd)

history = model.fit(training_data, target_data, nb_epoch=10000, batch_size=4, verbose=0)

print(model.predict(validation_data))
```

**UPDATE**

I tried to follow the advice and used more training data with no success so far.

My training set looks like this now

```
training_data = np.array([[0,0,0,
                           0,0,0,
                           0,0,0],
                          [0,0,1,
                           0,0,0,
                           1,0,0],
                          [0,0,1,
                           0,1,0,
                           0,0,1],
                          [1,0,1,
                           0,1,0,
                           0,0,0],
                          [0,0,0,
                           0,1,0,
                           1,0,1],
                          [1,0,0,
                           0,0,0,
                           0,0,0],
                          [0,0,0,
                           0,0,0,
                           1,0,0],
                          [0,0,0,
                           0,1,0,
                           0,0,1],
                          [1,0,1,
                           0,0,0,
                           0,0,0],
                          [0,0,0,
                           0,0,0,
                           0,0,1],
                          [1,1,0,
                           0,0,0,
                           0,0,0],
                          [0,0,0,
                           1,0,0,
                           1,0,0],
                          [0,0,0,
                           1,1,0,
                           0,0,0],
                          [0,0,0,
                           0,0,1,
                           0,0,1],
                          [0,0,0,
                           0,0,0,
                           0,1,1],
                          [1,0,0,
                           1,0,0,
                           1,0,0],
                          [1,1,1,
                           0,0,0,
                           0,0,0],
                          [0,0,0,
                           0,0,0,
                           1,1,1],
                          [0,0,1,
                           0,1,0,
                           1,0,0],
                          [0,1,0,
                           0,1,0,
                           0,1,0]], "float32")

target_data = np.array([[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1]], "float32")
```

Considering that I only count patterns of `1` as wins there are only 8 different win states for the way I represent the data. I made the NN see 5 of them so that I still have 3 to test against to see if the generalization works. I'm now feeding it 15 states that it should not consider a win.

However, the outcome for my validation seems to actually get worse.

```
[[  1.06987642e-07]
 [  4.72647212e-02]
 [  1.97011139e-03]
 [  2.93282426e-07]]
```

Things I tried:

1. Changing from *sigmoid*  to *softmax*
2. Adding more neurons
3. Adding more layer
4. A mix of all of the above

Comment: Re-posted from [AI beta](http://ai.stackexchange.com/q/1570/8) ([access link](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93481/artificial-intelligence/visit)).

Comment: Have you tried generating a much larger sample base before predicting?

Comment: You are solving here a regression problem? seems it could work as a classification problem, which means using softmax outputs and binary cross entropy loss.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I also tried that with no success. I'm thinking it's really the size of the grid that is too small. I'll try with a bigger grid so that I have more space to draw positive samples without taking all the samples to proof generalization.

Comment: @Christoph what do you mean no success? What accuracy did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with this for a while I think I learned enough to add a valuable answer as well.

**1. Grid size**

Increasing the size of the grid will make it much easier to come up with more samples for the training while still leaving enough room for validation data that the NN won't see during the training. I'm not saying it can't be done for a `3 x 3` grid but increasing the size of the grid will definitely help. I ended up increasing the size to `6 x 6` and looking for straight lines of a min length of four connected points.

**2. Data representation**

Representing the data in a one dimensional vector isn't optimal.

Think about it. When we want to represent the following line in our grid...

```
[0,1,0,0,0,0,
 0,1,0,0,0,0,
 0,1,0,0,0,0,
 0,1,0,0,0,0,
 0,0,0,0,0,0,
 0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

...how should our NN know that what we mean isn't actually this pattern in a grid of size `3 x 12`?

```
[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,
 0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,
 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

We can provide much more context to our NN if we represent the data in a way that the NN knows we are talking about a grid of size `6 x 6`.

```
[[0,1,0,0,0,0],
 [0,1,0,0,0,0],
 [0,1,0,0,0,0],
 [0,1,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

The good news is that we can do exactly that using a `Convolution2D` layer in keras.

**3. Target data representation**

It's not only helpful to rethink the representation of our training data, we can also tweak the representation of our target data. Initially I wanted to go with with a binary question: Does this grid contain a straight line or not? 1 or 0.

Turns out we can do much better by using the same shape for our target data that we use for our input data and redefine our question as: Does this pixel belong to a straight line or not? So, considering we have an input sample that looks like this:

```
[[0,1,1,0,0,1],
 [0,1,0,1,0,0],
 [0,1,0,0,1,0],
 [0,1,0,0,0,1],
 [0,0,0,1,0,0],
 [1,0,1,0,0,0]]
```

Our target output would look like this.

```
[[0,1,1,0,0,0],
 [0,1,0,1,0,0],
 [0,1,0,0,1,0],
 [0,1,0,0,0,1],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

That way we're giving the NN much more context about we are actually looking for. Think about it, if **you** had to make sense of these samples I'm sure this target data representation would also hint your brain much better compared to a target data representation that is just `0` or `1`.

Now the question is. How can we model our NN to have a target shape that is of the same shape as our input data? Because what usually happens is that each convolutional layer slices the grid in smaller grids to look for certain features which effectively then changes the shape of our data that is passed to the next layer.

However we can set `border_mode='same'` for our convolutional layers which essentially fills up the smaller grids with a border of zeros so that the original shape is preserved.

**4. Measure**

Measuring the performance of our model is the key to make the right adjustments. In particular, we want to see how accurate the predictions of our NN are for the training data and the validation data. Having these numbers gives us the right hints.

For instance if the accurancy for the predictions of our training data goes up while the accuracy of the predictions for our validation data is stale or even declines, that means that our NN is *overfitting*. That means, it basically *memorizes* the training data but it doesn't actually generalize the learnings so that it can apply them to data it hasn't seen before (e.g. our validation data).

There are three things we want to do:

A.) we want to set `validation_data = (val_input_data, val_target_data)` when we call `model.fit(...)` so that keras can inform us about the accuracy for our validation data after each epoch.

B.) we want to set `verbose=2` when we call `model.fit(...)` so that keras actually prints out the progress after each epoch.

C.) we want to set `metrics=['binary_accuracy']` when we call `model.compile(...)` to actually include the right metric in these progress logs that keras gives us after each epoch.

**5. Data generation**

Last but not least, as most of the other answers suggest. The more data, the better. I ended up writing a data generator that produces the training data and target data samples for me. My validation data is hand picked and I made sure that the generator **does not** generate training data that is identical with my validation data. I ended up training with 1000 samples.

**The final model**

This is the model I ended up with using. It uses a `Dropout` and a feature size of `64`. That said, you can play with these numbers and will notice there are lots of models that will work pretty well.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, input_shape=(1, 6, 6), activation='relu', border_mode='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu', border_mode='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Convolution2D(1, 1, 1, activation='sigmoid', border_mode='same'))
```

Answer (score 3):

I see your problem immediately: your training set is far too small.  Your problem space consists of the 512 corners a 9-dimensional hypercube.  Your training colours two of the corners green, and two others red.  You now somehow expect the trained model to have correctly intuited the proper colourings for the remaining 508 corners.

No general-purpose machine-learning algorithm will intuit the pattern of "does this board position contain any of the eight approved sequences of three evenly-spaced '1' values?" from only two positive and two negative examples.  For one thing, note that your training data has no row wins, does not exclude evenly-spaced points that aren't a win, and ... well, many other patterns in the space.

I expect that you'll need at *least* two dozen well-chosen examples on each side of the classification to get *any* appreciable performance from your model.  Think in terms of test cases: bits 1-2-3 make a win, but 3-4-5 does not; 3-5-7 make a win, but 1-3-5 and 2-4-6 do not.

Does this move you toward a solution?

One thing you might try is to generate random vectors and then classify them with a subroutine; feed these as training data.  Do more for testing and validation data.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! You're probably right. I haven't thought about 512 different states when thinking about a 3 x 3 grid. In fact can you explain the math behind it a little bit more. I get that it's 2^9. But why isn't it 9^2 for example? In other words, how do I calculate the number of different states in this case? Can you add this to your answer maybe?

In the meantime I extend my set of cases and see how it works out.

Comment: I updated my answer according to my latest experiments.

Comment: Each of 9 independent elements has 2 possible values.  That's 2*2*2 * 2*2*2 * 2*2*2, or 2^9 possibilities.  That much is basic combinatorics.  I'd rather not add it to the answer, because it's "underbrush" for the solution.  Adding an explanation of independence and probability computations is beyond the intended scope of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

What Prune said makes a lot of sense. Given that your problem space is 138 terminal board positions (and that's excluding rotations and reflections! - see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe)) it is very unlikely that the learning algorithm can sufficiently adjust the weights and biases, just by training on a 4-entry data set. I had a similar experience in one of my "learning experiments", where, even though the net was trained on the complete data set, because the set was very small, I ended up having to train it over multiple epochs until it was able to output decent predictions.

I think what's important to remember here is that what training a FF neural net ultimately does is to fine-tune weights and biases so that the loss function is minimised as much as possible. The lower the loss, the closer the predictions get to the expected outputs and the better the neural net gets. This means the more training data the merrier :)

I found this complete [training set](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Tic-Tac-Toe+Endgame) for tic tac toe, though it's not in the format that you set out with, but who knows, perhaps it will be useful for you. I would be curious to know, what the min subset of that training set would be, for the net to start making reliable predictions :P

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting problem. I think you're really wanting your system to recognize "lines", but as others have said, with so little training data it's hard for the system to generalize.

A different and counterintuitive approach might be to start with a *larger* board, say, 10x10, not 3x3, and generate random lines in that space and try to make the model learn them. You might explore convolutional networks in that case. This would be a lot like the handwritten digit recognition problem, and I expect it would succeed easily. Once your system is good at recognizing lines, maybe you can creatively adapt it somehow and scale it down to recognize the tiny lines in the 3x3 case.

(That said, I think you can learn this particular 3x3 problem just by giving your network ALL the data. It might be too small for generalization, so I wouldn't even try in this case. After all, in training a net to learn the binary XOR function, we just fee it all 4 examples -- the complete space. You can't train it reliably from just 3 examples.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. In fact, what I'm trying to do is to recognize lines. I also came to the conclusion that I should try it out with a larger grid. Just haven't had the chance to try it. I'll post back once I tried it out. But just to be sure, the way I represent the lines in the grid as a vector should work, right? At some point I got so confused wether I should group each row in it's own vector so that I end up with a 3 dimensional training set...but I couldn't even figure out how to make that work.

Comment: Good question -- this depends. If you want to actually build a convolutional net you need the 2D structure. But if you're trying to essentially memorize the answers in a small space like 3x3 that's not needed. And even in the larger grid case I think you can get it to work ok with a regular net (non-convolutional) if you give it enough training data, but it will not generalize as naturally. I think it would be instructive if you could to try both approaches and report back on your findings here! Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are problems here beyond a small data set, and these lie in your representation of the game state. In Tic-Tac-Toe, there are three possible states for each space on the board at any given time: [X], [O], or empty []. Furthermore there are conditions on the game which limit possible board configurations. i.e. there can be no more then n+1 [X] squares, given n [O] squares. I suggest going back and thinking about how to represent the three-state nature of the game-squares.

Comment: I think you are right if I was about to have the entire game flow be controlled by AI. But I'm not trying to have AI enforce the rules of the game. I really just want to recognize a pattern. Actually we don't even have to call it tic tac toe. So in my case, there aren't three states. It's really just a binary thing of either having a 0 or a 1 at a specific point in the grid.

Comment: The real issue here is that there are only 13 possible permutations that result in 'winning' out of a potential 138 possible board states. In other words the problem is a bit shallow to apply a deep learning strategy. In order to properly train the algorithm one would have to include almost all of the possible positive cases in the training set. I suggested using a three state system to provide more depth to the problem. –